# Deleting all elements of a Zend\Form\Collection (Fieldset with a DoctrineModule ObjectSelect)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I'm working on a ZF2 application which uses a ZF2 form plus DoctrineModule hydrator to create/update entities in a simple CRUD system.  The entity (Union) has a Doctrine OneToMany association with another entitiy (Team), and that association is represented by a `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` on the form site.  Everything works A-OK when creating a new entity or updating an existing entity using the form except for one case: emptying the assocation collection of a pre-existing entity.  When I remove all the elements of the collection and click save the form is bounced back and each existing element of the collection shows the error `Value is required and can't be empty`.

Video showing the issue: http://youtu.be/3ucRb6X61c8

Code:

- Controller: [Class](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/CompetitionAdmin/src/Controller/UnionAdminController.php), [View Scripts](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/CompetitionAdmin/view/usa-rugby-stats/competition-admin/union-admin/form.phtml)
- Service: [Class](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Service/UnionService.php), [Factory](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Service/UnionServiceFactory.php)
- Form: [Factory](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Form/UnionCreateFormFactory.php)
- Fieldsets:

  - UnionFieldset: [Class](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Form/Fieldset/UnionFieldset.php), [Factory](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Form/Fieldset/UnionFieldsetFactory.php)
  - Union\TeamFieldset: [Class](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Form/Fieldset/Union/TeamFieldset.php), [Factory](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Form/Fieldset/Union/TeamFieldsetFactory.php)
- Entities:

  - Union: [Class](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Entity/Union.php), [XML](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/config/doctrine/self/UsaRugbyStats.Competition.Entity.Union.dcm.xml)
  - Team: [Class](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/Entity/Team.php), [XML](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/config/doctrine/self/UsaRugbyStats.Competition.Entity.Team.dcm.xml)

It seems that the issue boils down to the InputFilter, but I can't seem to pin down exactly what is wrong.  Removing up to (N-1) of the N entries of the collection works fine, so it's not a problem with the InputFilter structure itself.  Perhaps when the POSTed collection is empty, `Zend\Form` doesn't remove the existing NotEmpty validator assigned to each element of the `teams` collection?

A custom input filter is provided ([see here](https://github.com/adamlundrigan/USARugby-Stats/blob/develop/module/UsaRugbyStats/Competition/src/InputFilter/UnionFilter.php)) for the Union fieldset, but the `teams` collection element doesn't have an input listed.  I've also tried both removing the custom InputFilter entirely and adding a suitable InputFilter definition for the `teams` collection, but the end result is the same.

Anyone out there have any insight on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This is really weird situation. Seems like issue [4492](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4492) and/or [6079](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6079) on github related with this.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this I updated the controller which receives the form POST to detect when the collection has been emptied from the client side and manually empty the collection on the entity:

```
if ( !isset($data['union']['teams']) || empty($data['union']['teams']) ) {
    $entity->removeTeams($entity->getTeams());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having your `TeamFieldset` implement `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface` and then add the following method to the fieldset:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array(
        'id' => array(
            'required' => false,
        )
    );
}
```

Modified `TeamFieldset`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/08bf222baa5c250b4614

Comment: That gives me a slightly different result.  The collection elements no longer have the error associated with them, and so the form validates,  but the entity still pops out the other side with the original collection elements intact.

Somewhere along the line the fact that the POST request contains no trace of the `teams` collection causes the form to "forget" to call `removeTeams` on the entity to clear out the collection.